# Using directive in header that should affect only this file

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files

There is a header file that declare classes in namespace `long::name::space::name`

And also I want specialize some templates in global namespace for this classes, i.e.

```
template<typename T>
class GlobalClass<NSClass<T>> {

}
...
```

It's quite annoying to write namespace name every time, so I would like to use some kind of using directive, but it isn't good idea to push this name to global namespace?

Is there way to do something to make typing shorter, but not add anything to global namespace?

I know one solution but It's quite ugly:

```
#define NS long::name::space::name
//use NS here
#undef NS
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `#define` is ugly?  Or have you just been conditioned to automatically recoil and use the word "ugly" whenever you see preprocessor directives?

Comment: I'm sure it seems not to be beautiful for me

Answer (score 1):

You can give namespaces short aliases (keep in mind that `long` is a keyword in C++):

```
namespace SN = longy::name::space::name;

// ...

SN::my_class obj; // Resolves into longy::name::space::name::my_class
```